# javascript: var is 'undefined' in mozilla, works on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mozilla

I cannot solve this problem, this function works well in chrome but in mozilla i get a "type error: rowTotal is undefined" in line "var rowValue = rowTotal.split('.').join('')"

Can somebody help me? haven't been able to figure it out mysel

```
function calculateTotal(){
    var table = document.getElementById("tablaListado");    
    var numFilas = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
    var count = 0;
    var total = 0;
    for(var i=1;i<(numFilas-1);i++){
        if(document.getElementById("sum_"+i).checked == true){
            var rowTotal = document.getElementById("total_"+i).innerText;
            var rowValue = rowTotal.split('.').join('');
            total =  parseInt(rowValue) + total;
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    showDiv(total, count);
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: There could well be issues with your HTML. Please provide the relevant parts of that. You could well be using the same id more than once.

Comment: You should set a breakpoint or `console.log()` on the rowTotal assignment line and see what `document.getElementById("total_"+i)` points to when it gives you problems in chrome.  This is simple debugging technique.  Find out why you're getting undefined by looking at the intermediate steps and gathering more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.innerText` is not supported by Firefox, but you can use `.textContent` instead. Unfortunately, `.textContent` is not supported by IE, so you need to test for it first.

You can use this function:

```
function getInnerText(elementID)
{
  if(typeOf(document.getElementById(elementID).innerText) != "undefined")
  {
    return document.getElementById(elementID).innerText;
  }
  else
  {
    return document.getElementById(elementID).textContent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm, I'm baffled by the speed of all the answers, thank you very much!